# Output list of for loop as variable

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I am trying to get the output of hostnames based on OS type (want only RedHat server hostnames) set as a variable.

but my code keeps spitting out the string *RedHat* along with each hostname.

```
minions=$(salt-run manage.up | cut -a " " -f2)

hosts=$(for minion in ${minions[@]}; do salt ${minion} grains.items | grep "os_family:" | grep RedHat && echo ${minion}; done)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `grep` will ouput the results of the pattern match.

If your version of `grep` supports it ... the `-q` flag will suppress the output:

```
... | grep -q RedHat && echo ${minion}; done)
```

Alternatively, redirect the output  to `/dev/null`:

```
... | grep RedHat >/dev/null && echo ${minion}; done)
```